# Mocking a path which is given in a method - Python

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

How can I mock the path (".test/locations.yml), because it does not exist in this project where I run my test. It exists in the CI environment.

I test my function get_matches_mr and then it says path location file not found

Do you have any idea?

Code

```
def read_location_file():
    locations_file_path = os.path.join(".test/location.yml")

    if not os.path.isfile(locations_file_path):
        raise RuntimeError("Location file not found: " + locations_file_path)
    with open(locations_file_path, "r") as infile:
        location_file = yaml.safe_load(infile.read())
        test_locations= location_file["paths"]
    return test_locations



def get_matches_mr(self):

    merge_request = MergeRequest()
    locations = self.read_location_file()
    data_locations= merge_request.get_matches(locations)

    return data_locations
```

Comment: You are probably better of patching `read_location_file`, if you don't want to test its functionality. Otherwise you either have to patch all the used file system methods (`os.path.isfile`, `open`, `yaml_safe_load`), or you can use a file system mock like `pyfakefs`, where you set up the needed file.

Comment: Don't hard-code the path in the first place. Make it a function argument; then you can test the function by passing any path you like.

Comment: The call to `os.path.join` is somewhat pointless; you aren't joining anything.

Comment: Better yet, don't pass a path, either; pass the file-like object you would create. The purpose of `read_location_file` should be to parse and extract the desired locations; let the caller worry about finding and opening the appropriate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like suggested in the comment, I would also say the best way to test such a scenario is to mock `read_location_file`. Because mocking the file system methods like `os.path.join` would mean that you limit the test to a certain implementation, which is a bad practice. The unit test suite should not know about the implementation detail, but only about the interfaces to be tested. Usually, in test driven development you write the test before the logic is implemented. This way you would not even know `os.path.join` is used.

The following code shows how to mock the `read_location_file` method. Assuming the class containing your two methods is called `ClassToBeTested` (replace with your actual class name).

```
import os.path

from class_to_test import ClassToBeTested


def test_function_to_test(tmpdir, monkeypatch):
    def mockreturn():
        return [
            os.path.join(tmpdir, "sample/path/a"),
            os.path.join(tmpdir, "sample/path/b"),
            os.path.join(tmpdir, "sample/path/c"),
        ]

    monkeypatch.setattr(ClassToBeTested, 'read_location_file', mockreturn)

    c = ClassToBeTested()
    assert c.get_matches_mr()
```

Note: I use the fixtures [`tmpdir`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html) and [`monkeypatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html), which are both built-ins of pytest:

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216842/6180150) to find some info about `tmpdir` (in the linked answer I explained `tmp_path`, but it provides the same concept as `tmpdir`; the difference is `tmp_path` returns a `pathlib.Path` object, and `tmpdir` returns a `py.path.local` object).
- `monkeypatch` is a pytest fixture that provides methods for mocking/patching of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Split your function into two parts:

1. Finding and opening the correct file.
2. Reading and parsing the opened file.

Your function only does the second part; the call can be responsible for the first part.

```
def read_location_file(infile):
    location_file = yaml.safe_load(infile.read())
    test_locations= location_file["paths"]
    return test_locations
```

Your test code can then use something like `io.StringIO` to verify that your function can parse it correctly.

```
def test_read_location():
    assert read_location_file(io.StringIO("...")) == ...
```

Your production code will handle opening the file:

```
with open(location_file_path) as f:
    locations = read_location_file(f)
```